# sql Задача- удалить все записи о преподавании предмета с названием 'PE' и количеством студентов менее 15

Tags: sql, postgresql, delete

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Teachers;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Subjects;

CREATE TABLE Subjects
(subject int Primary key,
 details varchar not null,
 credit int
);

INSERT INTO Subjects  (subject,details,credit) VALUES
(1111,'Matan',4),
(2222,'Biolog',8),
(3333,'Leng',3),
(4444,'PE',5);

CREATE TABLE Teachers
(teacher_id int Primary key,
 last_name varchar(255) Not NULL,
 group_code varchar(255) not null,
 hours integer,
 students integer,
 subject int References Subjects(subject)
);
INSERT INTO Teachers (teacher_id,last_name,group_code,hours,students,subject) values
(11,'Tarasuk','pmi27',11,27,1111),
(22,'Markiz','pmi21',10,24,4444),
(33,'Orst','pmi32',8,3,2222),
(44,'Krazy','pmi43',30,20,2222);

--удаление не работает
DELETE FROM Subjects sub
USING Teachers m
WHERE  sub.subject = sub.subject and m.students<25;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Teachers;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Subjects;

CREATE TABLE Subjects
(subject int Primary key,
 details varchar not null,
 credit int
);

INSERT INTO Subjects  (subject,details,credit) VALUES
(1111,'Matan',4),
(2222,'Biolog',8),
(3333,'Leng',3),
(4444,'PE',5);

CREATE TABLE Teachers
(teacher_id int Primary key,
 last_name varchar(255) Not NULL,
 group_code varchar(255) not null,
 hours integer,
 students integer,
 subject int References Subjects(subject)
);
INSERT INTO Teachers (teacher_id,last_name,group_code,hours,students,subject) values
(11,'Tarasuk','pmi27',11,27,1111),
(22,'Markiz','pmi21',10,24,4444),
(33,'Orst','pmi32',8,3,2222),
(44,'Krazy','pmi43',30,20,2222);

--удаление не работает

DELETE FROM Teachers m
USING Subjects sub
WHERE  sub.subject = m.subject and m.students<25;

--    DELETE FROM Subjects sub
--    USING Teachers m
--    WHERE  sub.subject = m.subject and m.students<25;
```

У вас проблема связных таблиц